# How to restart my minikube kubernetes cluster in AWS instance, after stopping and starting that instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, minikube

I had a t2.micro server running where i had deployed Minikube, however due to memory issue i scared up the server size. For which i had to stop and start the instance.

But now after restarting, when i try with kubectl commands i get the below error.

```
root@ip-172-31-23-231:~# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 172.31.23.231:6443 was refused - did you 
specify the right host or port?
```

So, how can i bring my earlier kube cluster up once i restart my AWS instance?

Comment: try with `minikube status`, Is minikube running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error. In my case minikube was not running. I started it with

```
minikube start
```

Comment: Is it expected behaviour that this takes a looooooong time?

Answer (score 3):

There are few methods to fix this issue.

**Solution: 1**
If all components are `Stopped` and if you run some commands you will get information to start the cluster again. This is usually solving this kind of issue. Starting the `minikube` cluster again won't delete anything from your cluster.

***Example***

```
$ minikube logs
  The control plane node must be running for this command
  To start a cluster, run: "minikube start"
---
$ minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Stopped
kubelet: Stopped
apiserver: Stopped
kubeconfig: Stopped
timeToStop: Nonexistent
---
$ minikube start
---
$ minikube status
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
timeToStop: Nonexistent
```

**Solution: 2** use followed commands

```
$ sudo -i
$ swapoff -a
$ exit
$ strace -eopenat kubectl version
```

**Solution: 3** Restart docker service

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

And wait ~20-40 seconds

**Solution: 4**
As the last option if everything else fails, you can delete and create a new `Minikube`.

```
$ minikube delete
  Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
  Deleting container "minikube" ...
---
$ minikube start
```

This option unfortunately will delete all your resources from the cluster. It will create cluster from scratch.

**Useful information and commands:**

- [Minikube Troubleshooting guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/troubleshooting/)
- `$ minikube logs`
- `$ minikube dashboard`
- `$ minikube status`

Answer (score 2):

check this : 
run -> `minikube status`

```
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: ...
```

if isn't running -> `minikube start`

then check the dashboard -> `minikube dashboard`